# Batter not sticking to aluminum rosette

Tags: equipment

The batter doesn’t stick to the rosette when I dip it, it falls off. What am I doing wrong?

I made the batter, heated the rosette for 15 minutes, and dipped it into batter, which didn't stick.

Comment: Are you sure the mold is hot enough? It should sizzle when put into the batter, which should help stick it to the mold. Are you heating in oil or just in the oven?